# remove one property from mongoose 'toJSON' support

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose's toJSON support as below:

```
userSchema.set('toJSON', { getters: true, virtuals: true, minimize: false })
```

now in the returned result from a mongoose object's toJSON() method call, I want to remove certain sensitive fields. How to do that?

In different way to explain the issue:

Some certain fields like 'password', 'token' which we would need only in query, but not in returned result, how to hide them from returning from all kind of queries?

Update: This finally what I ended up with and working like a charm:

```
userSchema.options.toJSON = {
    getters: true,
    virtuals: true,
    minimize: false,
    transform: function (doc, ret, options) {
      delete ret.password
      delete ret.authToken
      return ret
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can customize how toJSON works on your schema like this:

```
/**
  * adjust toJSON transformation
  */ 
mySchema.options.toJSON = {
    transform: function(doc, ret, options) {
        ret.id = ret._id;
        delete ret.password;
        delete ret.token;
        delete ret._id;
        delete ret.__v;
        return ret;
    }
};
```

`doc` is the document to be serialized, `ret` is the plain JS object that will be transformed into JSON. You may then manipulate `ret` however you want.

Comment: Thanks for the clue. it helped me getting to what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer help me as well. btw, Do you know how to show these hidden fields when you want it to be display.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I remove the password field.

```
 userSchema.methods.toJSON = function() {
  var obj = this.toObject();
  delete obj.password;
  return obj;
}
```