# Mongoose - excluding _v from resulting JSON

Tags: mongoose, version

I want to remove the `_v` attribute from mongoose's resulting JSON to minimize my API response size, but I don't want to disable it in the DB by the `versionKey` option. What is the most convenient way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32390996/remove-one-property-from-mongoose-tojson-support

Answer (score 0):

```
User.find().select("-__v").exec(function(err, data){
    console.log(data);
})
```

or you can use

```
User.find({}, { "__v" : 0 } , function(err, data) {
});
```

It will exclude `__v` from the result data.

Comment: Is there any other way to apply this to all queries?